# Python - 3D mapping, without 3D engines

Tags: python, 3d, mapping, textures, cube

Does anyone know how to do this?
I want to be able to map a texture to a 3d cube in Python.

here's my code so far,

```
from pygame import gfxdraw
import pygame, sys, math

def rotate2d(pos,rad): x,y=pos; s,c = math.sin(rad),math.cos(rad); return x*c-y*s,y*c+x*s

class Cam:
    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0,0),rot=(0,0)):
        self.pos=list(pos)
        self.rot=list(rot)
    def events(self,event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            x,y = event.rel
            x/=200;y/=200
            self.rot[0]+=y; self.rot[1]+=x
    def update(self,dt,key):
        s=dt*10

        if key[pygame.K_q]: self.pos[1]+=s
        if key[pygame.K_e]: self.pos[1]-=s

        x,y = s*math.sin(self.rot[1]),s*math.cos(self.rot[1])

        if key[pygame.K_w]: self.pos[0]+=x;self.pos[2]+=y
        if key[pygame.K_s]: self.pos[0]-=x;self.pos[2]-=y
        if key[pygame.K_a]: self.pos[0]-=y;self.pos[2]+=x
        if key[pygame.K_d]: self.pos[0]+=y;self.pos[2]-=x

class Cube:
    vertices = (-1,-1,-1),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(-1,1,1)
    edges = (0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,4),(0,4),(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)
    faces = (0,1,2,3),(4,5,6,7),(0,1,5,4),(2,3,7,6),(0,3,7,4),(1,2,6,5)
    colors = (255,0,0),(0,255,0),(0,0,255),(255,255,0),(255,0,255),(0,255,255)

    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0,0)):
        x,y,z = pos
        self.verts = [(x+X/2,y+Y/2,z+Z/2) for X,Y,Z in self.vertices]

pygame.init()
w,h = 400,400; cx,cy = w//2,h//2; fov = min(w,h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
cam=Cam((0,0,-5))
pygame.event.get(); pygame.mouse.get_rel()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0); pygame.event.set_grab(1);

i1 = pygame.image.load("Untitled.png")

cubes = [Cube((0,0,0)),Cube((-2,0,0)),Cube((2,0,0))]

while True:
    dt = clock.tick()/1000

    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit();sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: pygame.quit();sys.exit()
    cam.events(event)
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    face_list = []; face_color = []; depth = []

    for obj in cubes:

        vert_list = []; screen_coords = []
        for x,y,z in obj.verts:
            x-=cam.pos[0]
            y-=cam.pos[1]
            z-=cam.pos[2]
            x,z = rotate2d((x,z),cam.rot[1])
            y,z = rotate2d((y,z),cam.rot[0])
            vert_list += [(x,y,z)]
            f=fov/z
            x,y = x*f,y*f
            screen_coords+=[(cx+int(x),cy+int(y))]

        for f in range(len(obj.faces)):
            face = obj.faces[f]

            on_screen = False
            for i in face:
                x,y = screen_coords[i]
                if vert_list[i][2]>0 and x>0 and x<w and y>0 and y<h: on_screen = True; break

            if on_screen:

                coords = [screen_coords[i] for i in face]
                face_list += [coords]
                face_color += [obj.colors[f]]

                depth += [sum([sum(vert_list[j][i] for j in face)**2 for i in range(3)])]
    order = sorted(range(len(face_list)),key=lambda i: depth[i],reverse=1)

    for i in order:
        try:
            x-=cam.pos[0]
            y-=cam.pos[1]
            z-=cam.pos[2]
            x,z = rotate2d((x,z),cam.rot[1])
            y,z = rotate2d((y,z),cam.rot[0])
            vert_list += [(x,y,z)]
            f=fov/z
            x,y = x*f,y*f
            #x2 = str(x)
            #x2 = int(x2.split('.')[0])
            #{
            # HERE IS THE TEXTURED POLYGON PART!!!!! VVVVVVVV
            pygame.gfxdraw.textured_polygon(screen, face_list[i], i1, 0, 0) # !!!
            #}
        except:
            pass

    pygame.display.flip()

    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    cam.update(dt/10,key)
```

So far I'm using gfxdraw.textured_polygon, however, that's meant for 2d. So it looks masked and weird. I've tried using the x,y values instead of the 0,0 in the offsetting part.

I followed this tutorial to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4E9iq0BixA

Any help wanted.

If you need anything else please ask.

Comment: I'm impressed you even got to the cube ;) But I suggest you use PyOpenGL, as Pygame was not really made to do 3d.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm really doing this for fun rather than practicality. :)

Thanks for the compliment too ;)

Comment: Yeah, Pygame is really just for 2d. But Maybe there is a way to map 3d textures in Pygame.

Comment: Yeah, I hope so :)